# viewForHeaderInSection is called only once in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've exhausted the Google on this one, though I'm sure it's something quite embarrassingly simple.

I am trying to create a UITableView representing 25 (let's say) objects in 25 sections of 1 row each.

The custom cells I am creating show up fine (all 25 of them, in the right order). I would like a section header view to be displayed above each object.

The problem is that only one section header view (the first) is being displayed.

Judicious NSLogging tells me that viewForHeaderInSection is called only once, although heightForHeaderInSection is called 2x per object. I am returning 25 from numberOfSectionsInTableView, and 1 from numberOfRowsInSection.

I am constructing a UIView in viewForHeaderInSection by doing `UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, viewHeight)]` and then adding a UILabel and a UIButton. I am not subclassing UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Not sure if this makes a difference here.

Any ideas?

Relevant code:

Number of sections and rows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.objects count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

Height and Cell for rows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 390;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // add custom content to cell

    return cell;
}
```

Height and view for Headers:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 60;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"in viewForHeaderInSection %ld", (long)section); // I only see this once
    NSLog(@"return view for section %ld", section);         // this is 0 when I see it

    // gather content for header
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, viewHeight)];
    // add content to header (displays correctly)

    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Though it too late. after 30 mins fighting I found a solution in xCode 8.1. I am putting it which may help to other.

// After adding the bellow **delegate method**, I found this called multiple times

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   return 30.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but a solution to this problem just occurred to me as I was formatting the above: If each cell needs a header, just build the header content into the cell, rather than trying to put it in a separate header view. sigh...

Still interested to know why `viewForHeaderInSection` seems to be called only once, though.

Comment: You should really be dequeing table view section headers like you do for cells. Essentially you have created a single instance of UIView for 25 different sections....If you wanted to just get it working quickly use titleForSection: method and then you will see if you at least get your proper sectioning. But moral of the story is dequeue a table view header properly like cells and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

add this delegate method

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView heightForFooterInSection: (NSInteger) section
```